# Bug when adding logo to the title in ImpressPages

Tags: image, content-management-system, graphical-logo, impresspages

I have tried to add logo to my impresspages, instead of default title. However after I uploaded logo into "Image logo" section of the title, it showed it black. Now I cannot change it: whenever I go to "Image Logo" section it is empty: no image selection buttons, nothing. Obviously it is some kind of bug, but how can I revert it back now? Do I have to reinstall ImpressPages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fix for that. But not released yet: https://github.com/impresspages/ImpressPages/commit/7df78d610dad7d861be64e1a5513e2a3097158c2

Comment: Can you please advice how I can apply this fix? Do I need to modify the content of the "Ip/Internal/InlineManagement/assets/inlineManagement.min.js" and "Ip/Internal/InlineManagement/assets/src/inlineManagementLogo.js" files manually? Can I just copy/paste them from that website to my server?

Comment: You can wait for an update to be released, modify these files. Or download them from GitHub and replace.